# Use of across with str_ within a mutate

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I'd like to apply a character replacement to all columns of a tibble. I can do it for one column:

`starwars %>% mutate(name = str_replace_all(name, "-", ""))`

But I do not understand how to generalise to with `across()`:

```
starwars %>% mutate(
  across(everything(),
    str_replace_all("-", "")
    )
  )
```

Is it necessary to use the `purr` package here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. Use the dot notation to dynamically pass all columns specified in the everything() command to your string function.

```
library(tidyverse)
starwars %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),
         ~str_replace_all(., "-", "")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use an anonymous function, which I personally find more intuitive and flexible than the dot notation:

```
starwars %>% mutate(
  across(everything(),
    function(x) str_replace_all(x,"-", "")
    )
  )
```